# Loading GIF in hidden DIV Not Animating in Firefox

Tags: forms, firefox, animation, static, loader

I'm showing a hidden DIV that contains an animated GIF when a form is submitted, works fine in Chrome/IE11/Edge but GIF does not animate in Firefox if anyone can tell why that happnes? Code as so:

```
onSubmit="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('loadergif').src='updating.gif';"
```

Hidden container like so:

```
<div id="overlay">
<div id="loader-container"><img src="updating.gif" width="204" height="85" alt="" id="loadergif"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `src='updating.gif'`? The `img` already has the source.

Comment: workaround for IE

Answer (score 0):

Instead of GIF I just used HTML5 Video and that fixes the issue

Show the DIV on submit:

```
onSubmit="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block';"
```

The DIV:

```
<div id="overlay">
<div id="loader-container">
  <video autoplay loop>
    <source src="updating.mp4">
    <source src="updating.webm">
    <source src="updating.ogv">
  </video>
</div>
</div>
```

Keeps it simple!